# React-router v6: Pass state in <Route>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In the following example, `<Header>` will render anytime there is a change in the routing path due to `useLocation()`. Moreover, `<Header>` will return prior to `<Home>` or `<Info>`.  What I want is to pass label 's value into `<Header>` anytime the route does change. How is that feasible?

```
 <App> component:
   const App = ()=>{
     return (
       <BrowserRouter>
          <Header />
          <Routes>    
            <Route
               path="/"
               element={<Home label={"Central"} />} />
            /> 
            <Route
               path="/info"
               element={<Info label={"Auxiliary"} />} />
            /> 
          </Routes>
       </BrowserRouter>
     )
   }



 <Header> component:
  const Header = props => {
     const location = useLocation();
      return (
        // want something like that... 
        {location.state.label}
      )
  }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to pass props to the routed component, or pass state during the route transition from one page to another? These are two different things.

Comment: What is this `Header` component? Can you provide a complete and comprehensive [mcve] that includes all the relevant code you are trying to work with and use, and clearly explain the use case and any issues you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass props to a routed component, and these are just regular old React props, accessed via the `props` object.

Example:

```
<Route path="/toy" element={<Toy label="Toy story" />} />
```

...

```
const Toy = ({ label }) => {
  // reference the passed label prop in the component scope

  ...
};
```

It doesn't matter where this value comes from. The component rendering the routes can have some local state and pass it down.

Example:

```
const [label, setLabel] = React.useState("Toy Story");

...

<Route path="/toy" element={<Toy label={label} />} />
```

...

```
const Toy = ({ label }) => {
  // reference the passed label prop in the component scope

  ...
};
```

### Update

Since you want to display some value in the `Header` based upon a matched route I suggest creating a layout route that holds some `label` state that is provided in an React Context, and create a route component wrapper that takes the `label` prop and updates the state in the layout route for the displayed label.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Outlet,
  useOutletContext
} from "react-router-dom";

const HeaderLayout = () => {
  const [label, setLabel] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{label}</h1> // <-- Header UI here
      <Outlet context={{ setLabel }} />
    </>
  );
};

const Wrapper = ({ children, label }) => {
  const { setLabel } = useOutletContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLabel(label);
  }, [label, setLabel]);

  return children;
};
```

Wrap all the routes in the layout route rendering `HeaderLayout`, and wrap the individual routed components with the `Wrapper` wrapper component and pass the `label` prop to it instead of the routed component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<HeaderLayout />}>
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={
        <Wrapper label={"Central"}>
          <Home />
        </Wrapper>
      }
    />
    <Route
      path="/info"
      element={
        <Wrapper label={"Auxiliary"}>
          <Info />
        </Wrapper>
      }
    />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

The `Wrapper` handles the label and update the context so this logic is completely decoupled from any specific component you want to display on any specific route path.

[image: Edit react-router-v6-pass-state-in-route]

Comment: Read again my question please since I have added more details. I want to create the state inside `<Route>` if that's possible. I do not know how to make it more clear.

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper Do you mean you want the parent component rendering the routes to have some state that is passed to the routed component?

Comment: Basically, what I want is to re-render (via useLocation()) everytime there is a routing, another component (<Header />) whose content depends on the route. Hence, I want to having set the state when <Header> will render.

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper Ok, clearly there are missing details. Let's take this conversation out to the main post.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hopefully, it will be clear now. Thanks

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper Yes, that did make it clearer. I've updated my answer with a proposed solution to my understanding of the desired behavior you are looking for. Please take another look when you can.